# Describe Riemann Surface of this function

Tags: complex-analysis

What would be the Riemann surface associated with the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left( z+\frac{1}{z}\right)$?

Answer (score 0):

The mapping is conjugate to $z^2$ using a Mobius transformation. The fixed points of $f$ are $1,-1,\infty$ which get mapped to $0,\infty,1$, respectively, for $z^2$. Thus, the Riemann surface is the same as for $z^2$.

Comment: What is the Riemann surface for z^2?